# How to solve crashing app problem and FATAL EXCEPTION error?

Tags: java, android

I am using the latest version of android studio and trying to pass image from one activity to another, but the following code is not performing as per expectation. when I am clicking on the image the app is going to close the second activity is not opening and I am getting run time error. How do I solve it?

you can see whole code through this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16R-8gvAfq1lNiaBrbxYk8OQuap_evoMg?usp=sharing

Error:

```
2021-03-21 21:14:52.639 23412-23412/com.example.recyclerviewexample5 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.recyclerviewexample5, PID: 23412
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.recyclerviewexample5/com.example.recyclerviewexample5.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2005)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1673)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4762)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4691)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5081)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5049)
    at com.example.recyclerviewexample5.CustomRecyclerViewAdopter$1.onClick(CustomRecyclerViewAdopter.java:44)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6724)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6682)
    at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:797)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26479)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:962)
```

CustomRecyclerViewAdopter.java: (you may go through onClick function)

```
    package com.example.recyclerviewexample5;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CustomRecyclerViewAdopter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    ArrayList personNames;
    ArrayList personImages;
    Context context;
    public CustomRecyclerViewAdopter(Context context, ArrayList personNames, ArrayList personImages) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personNames = personNames;
        this.personImages = personImages;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout_view, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // set the data in items
        MyViewHolder viewHolder= (MyViewHolder)holder;
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).name.setText( personNames.get(position).toString());
        ((MyViewHolder) holder).image.setImageResource((Integer) personImages.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Toast.makeText(context,"Person : "+(position+1),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", (Integer) personImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personNames.size();
    }
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        ImageView image;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.recyclerviewexample5;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView selectedImage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
        selectedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.selectedImage); // init a ImageView
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // get Intent which was set from adapter of Previous Activity
        selectedImage.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("image", 0)); // get image from Intent and set it in ImageView
//        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); // get Intent which was set from adapter of Previous Activity
//        int resId = bundle.getInt("image");
//        selectedImage.setImageResource(resId);
    }
}
```

activity_second.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="TODO" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recyclerviewexample5">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.RecyclerViewExample5">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.recyclerviewexample5/com.example.recyclerviewexample5.SecondActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: you've gone through all the trouble of finding a stack trace, perhaps you should read what it tells you, it might provide some useful hints towards solving your problems

Comment: I involved androidManifest code here, please let me know what line should I remove/edit/add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"></activity>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml, right after the MainActivity